# Auto-Resizing tableViewCells in iOS8 still truncate UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have been trying to use the new way to resize UITableView cells in iOS8 and to an extent, it works. I first make sure that the label is attached to the cell's container view at the top, bottom, trailing side and leading side which i was told to do on an online tutorial, though i feel that this is where the problem lies. In the viewDidLoad, I then put in the following lines:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 56
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

After watching the WWDC, it appears that this is pretty much all I need in regards to the cell, so then i went into the interface builder and set the "lines" property for the label to 0, again as instructed in the video. It resizes all of the cells as I would expect though it always makes them one line too small so that the full text doesn't fit in. Below is a screenshot of what it looks like. Please ask if you need more information or photos if it makes it easier for you to give me some advice. I realise this is probably a stupid error on my part but there are few places to look as iOS 8 is so new. Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: I believe they said there was a bug with `estimatedRowHeight` at WWDC. I'm not sure if that's been fixed since.

Comment: They did indeed, but they gave a supposed work around by making the amount of lines equal to 0. It may be that the work around no longer works and i may just have to wait until the Xcode 6 release

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm using Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to do all 3 suggestions to get it working:

Set the number of lines on the labels to 0.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` set the cell labels' text to an empty string before assigning the desired string.

calling `[tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidAppear:`.

I did try doing them individually and it doesn't work.

I had a minor issue after that however...The original layout of the text is in view before the table reloads and causes a weird looking text "flicker" when the text gets adjusted. So I created a bool and set the cell labels to hidden. When `viewWillAppear:` gets called i set that bool to true and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I unhide the labels if the bool is true.

In any case hopefully they get this fixed because it's an awesome feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into formatting issues with Auto-Resize, with UILabel objects in particular. What finally worked for me was to modify `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and first assign the UILabel's text to an empty string before assigning the actual string value, like this:

```
cell.myLabel.text = @"";
cell.myLabel.text = @"Here is the label's actual string value";
```

I have a feeling Apple still has some issues to work out with Auto-Resize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't been able to test it out but any help is great. I agree, it certainly does seem to have far more issues than I would expect.

Comment: Let me know how your test goes. The symptoms I saw seemed a bit different than yours, with the cells eventually displaying correctly after I scrolled my 15-cell list to the top and bottom several times. But once I did the empty string trick, it displayed correctly right from the start. By the way, I assume you're also calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your `viewDidAppear:` callback?

Comment: I will, and yes, I am

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem;

First, make sure content hugging priority is greater than another element.
Second, call `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Finally, define the `UITableViewDataSource` methods to make the height dynamic:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.rowHeight
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```