# Multi-line/Dynamic UILabel Truncating in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, ios8

I am using UILabels with `numberOfLines=0` and `lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` in a "dynamic" UITableViewCell . I utilize AutoLayout to attach the label to its container cell at the top, bottom, trailing and leading edges. In iOS7, the label's height updates dynamically with its content, however in iOS8 it truncates prematurely (usually at 1 line, but sometimes at 2). In iOS8, I have confirmed that the `intrinsicContentSize` of the label is dynamically updating as expected, but the label's frame is not following suit. Here is the difference seen between iOS7 and iOS8:

I have read of similar bugs in iOS8, but have been unable to implement a workaround. I have tried setting the label's text to `@""` and back to `@"Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter"` (as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270918/auto-resizing-tableviewcells-in-ios8-still-truncate-uilabel-text)), but that does not remedy the issue. Also notice that in iOS8, the cell size does increase according to the label's `intrinsicContentSize`, but for whatever reason, the height of the label itself does not. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I would be glad to provide more information as well.

**iOS 8**
[image: iOS 7 Example Image]

**iOS 7**
[image: iOS 8 Example Image]

Comment: Hello @gsheld, have you figure out a solution for the issue ? I have been searching in SO. Most of the answers said set the label preferredMaxLayoutWidth at layoutSubviews method with the label width. However, it is not working at all. :-(

Answer (score 3):

This is my walk around
subclass of UILabel, and override this function.

```
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
    limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
    CGRect rect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds
                    limitedToNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];

    float height = rect.size.height;
    int hightRound = (int)roundf(height);
    rect.size.height = hightRound;
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: Don't use roundf(height), use ceilf(height). Otherwise there's a 50% chance your label will still be truncated. Great, with that fix applied.